# htaccess too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have .htaccess in the root directory of web which should redirect all requests to https. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web\.php5\.sk$
RewriteRule ^$ www/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web\.php5\.sk$
RewriteRule (.*) www/$1 [L]
```

But it creates an endless loop which redirects from http to https and vice versa. Where could be the problem? First two lines comes from server administrator as response to my request for https. They handles lot of http requests from devices which are not able to make https request... Thanks.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: There is somenthing like 307 internal redirect. But what it means internal? Look at it https://web.php5.sk/

Comment: Try changing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http` (assuming you're not behind a proxy)

Comment: {REQUEST_SCHEME} =http is the same.

Comment: It was the problem of framework settings.

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend What about this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#replace this yourdomain.com into your domain name 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This is a simple, clean and tested code to redirect all traffic from `http` to `https` with `www` (you can also remove www from your URL anytime, just remove www from url something like this `https://yourdomain.com/$1`).

Comment: Thanks for your time. But the problem was in settings in php framework. It always redirects to http if it is not explicitly set to https.

Comment: @Čamo can you try to open your website in another browser or clear cache of your website from your current browser